# How to implement...? Finding an arc range given an angle

Tags: matlab, if-statement

implementing this on MATLAB for my project.

I have a circle divided up to 3 arcs. 
So the angle range of each arc is [0,120), [120,240), [240,360) degrees.

Right now I have a code that finds whether the angle lies in arc A, B, C given any theta.

```
theta = mod(theta,360);
if theta >= 0 && theta < 120
    Arc = A;
elseif theta >= 120 && theta < 240
   Arc = B;
elseif theta >= 240 && theta < 360
   Arc = C;
```

This works just fine. Here is the situation that I am struggling to get to:

The circle can rotate by the angle phi.

So for example, if the circle rotated clockwise 30 degrees, the range of my angle will be
[30,150), [150,270), [270,390)

How should I write my if statement to deal with this case? 
My theta input can range from 0 to infinity, so I tried to do modulus division to get to
[30,150), [150,270), [270,30)

but now I am stuck how to make it generalized so it can work for any input of theta
and phi input that ranges from [0,360)

Thanks in advance with your advise.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you know the angle the circle is rotated by (as you say, `phi = 30°`), then just use `theta-phi` instead of `theta`. The rest of the code stays the same:

```
theta = mod(theta-phi,360);
if theta >= 0 && theta < 120
   Arc = A;
elseif theta >= 120 && theta < 240
   Arc = B;
elseif theta >= 240 && theta < 360
   Arc = C;
```

<strike>Alternatively, you can *add* the `phi` to all angles:</strike>

```
theta = mod(theta,360);
ranges = mod([0 120; 120 240; 240 360])
if theta >= 0+phi && theta < 120+phi
   Arc = A;
elseif theta >= 120+phi && theta < 240+phi
   Arc = B;
elseif theta >= 240+phi && theta < 360+phi
   Arc = C;
```

Use whatever you find most intuitive; the performance impact of the six additions versus the single addition is completely negligible.

**EDIT:** forget the second method, it's far too messy.

Comment: With the first method, with theta = 380 and phi =30. I get "A", instead of "C".
Where as the second method leaves the region from 0 to 30 in dark area. (If I enter the same input, my arc would be undefined)

Comment: @user1426485: Right so you are; I must have been sleeping. Of course, the `mod` should be taken over `theta-phi`. The second method: forget it, it's way too messy to advise it under any circumstances. See my edit.

Comment: mod(theta-phi,360) was the trick I was missing! Thanks a lot for your comment. :)